# Getting tag count with jinstagram java

Tags: java, instagram-api

I'm learning how to use jinstagram but since there is no tutorials only the example in the project i'm not sure how to do certain stuff with the api.

I need to get the count of certains tags(for example how many photos with the tag #football), i think i can do it with this block of code:

```
  public void getMediaByTags(String tagName) throws Exception {
        TagMediaFeed recentMediaTags = instagram.getRecentMediaTags(tagName);
        printMediaFeedList(recentMediaTags.getData());

    }
```

but then again maybe there is already a function written in the api, anyone here who has already used jinstagram could help me with this?

Comment: `recentMediaTags.getData()` probably returns some sort of `Collection` or `Array`, and those have `size` and `length`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just want to get number of media for the given tag.

You can find that in given examples for jInstagram:

```
String tagName = "nofilter";
TagInfoFeed feed = instagram.getTagInfo(tagName);

TagInfoData tagData = feed.getTagInfo();
System.out.println("name : " + tagData.getTagName());
System.out.println("media_count : " + tagData.getMediaCount());
```